# Can't Embed Arial/ArialMT to PDF from Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2010, adobe-acrobat, microsoft-word-2013

I have a Word document in Cambria which I converted to PDF. However, the PDF oddly had **ArialMT font** in its properties that was **not embedded**.

Fiddling around a bit, I found that it was **inserting bullets** that was causing this issue. The bullets themselves were, appropriately, in Symbol font.

So it seems that the **tab space** after the bullet is being formatted as ArialMT.

When I export using Word's own export, I get Arial (not embedded) in PDF; when I use Adobe PDF for this, I get ArialMT (not embedded).

How do I resolve this issue?

And if I do not find a way to embed ArialMT, what issues could this create (this file will be disseminated widely)?

Comment: I would guess that being without a font that's used only for horizontal (spacing) tabs will have no effect, but that is only a guess.